# how to disply html style in flex with dynamically html data bind

Tags: apache-flex, styles

Hi i am new to Flex webapp.
I want to dynamically bind html text with flex webapplication. I fetch html data from database using webservice and binding with textarea control. While binding data it displaying all text but without style applied for text.
I tried following code for bind

```
 txtArea.textFlow = TextConverter.importToFlow(str,TextConverter.TEXT_FIELD_HTML_FORMAT);
```

Comment: How is the style information included in the HTML? Are they inline styles or coming from a style sheet? Keep in mind that CSS that works in your browser may not work exactly the same when you import it into a `TextFlow`. You might consider giving us a sample of the HTML/CSS, or even better, provide working example code that highlights the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your code above should work, most likely the html is malformed.

```
TextConverter.export(textArea.textFlow, TextConverter.TEXT_FIELD_HTML_FORMAT, ConversionType.STRING_TYPE).toString();
```

I use this code to generate the html, where I can reload and reapply the styles using the exact same code as you do.

Also you should start out with

```
<TEXTFORMAT>
```

in your saved htmltext if you aren't.